# Closure of a set of rational curves in a Fano manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth Fano variety of Picurd number one. Let $C$ be a minimal rational curve, that is, a curve in a minimal dominating component of rational curves in $X$. Let $d$ be the minimal degree. Let $(d_i)$ be a sequence of integers such that $d_i > d$  and there is a dominating component $K_i$ of rational curves in $X$ of degree $d_i$ for all $i$.
For each $i$, let $\{C_i^p \in K_i, p \in C\}$ be a set of rational curve parametrized by $C$ and $C_i= \cup C_i^p$.

Question: Can one find such a set of rational curves for each $i$, such that $\overline{C_i}= \overline{C_j}$ for all $i, j$ and $\text{dim}(\overline{C_i}) < \text{dim}{X}$, where $\overline{C_i}$ denotes the closure of C_i in $X$?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: please let me know what is not clear ?

Comment: There are too many things in this question that are not clearly specified.  As stated, of course this can happen: every hypersurface of degree $e$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ contains a linear $2$-plane if $(e+1)(e+2)/2 < (n-2)3$.  If the hypersurface is general and $n>e+1$, then the parameter space of rational curves of degree $d$ is irreducible and dominating for every $d>0$ by Riedl-Yang.  Yet you can choose $C$ and every $C_i$ to be contained in a fixed linear $2$-plane.  Are you asking whether this can happen for *every* general choice of $C$?

Comment: Here $C_i$ is not a curve. We do not know even whether it is variety or not. It just a set which is union of a set of rational curves  of degree $d_i$ indexed by $C$.

Comment: Can $\mathbb{P}^2$ contain a smooth rational curve of degree $d >2 $? I should have specified that the curves $C_i^p$ are smooth.

Comment: If you want the curves to be smooth, you can repeat the argument with linear $5$-planes, i.e., choose $n$ large enough so that $(e+1)(e+2)(e+3)(e+4)(e+5)/120<(n-5)6$.  Choose $C$ to be a line in the $5$-plane, and choose the curves $C_i$ to be curves of "ruling" in a general linear projection of $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ embedded in projective space by the linear system of bidegree $(1,d_i)$.

Comment: Can we do this for $d_i$ also large ? For example, if the sections of the linear system $(1, d_i)$ is bigger than $n$ ? After projecting to $\mathbb{P}^n$, will we get again smooth of degree $d_i$ ?  Can we do it for Fano with non-nef tangent bundle also ?

Comment: Yes, Jason's construction works for all $d$, and produces smooth curves in $\mathbb P^n$.